# Checking in two branches for a static website hosted on github pages

Tags: git, github

I'd like to use github pages to host my static website.
I imagine I have one branch for the site before being parsed (containing layouts, markdown contents, etc.) and another branch for the actual website. As far as I can tell, I can get github to uses this branch as my static website if I name it `gh-pages`.

Suppose I write a new post in markdown and I then run my static site generator that produce my website in a directory `/site`.

What is the git procedure for committing the markdown changes to the `master` branch and the stuff inside `/site` to the `gh-pages` branch?

Comment: Is this a user site or a project-specific site?

Comment: I presume it's a project site, because I haven't named the repo username.github.io?

Comment: Which do you want then? Is this your personal website or is it the webpage for one of your projects?

Comment: Does it matter? Isn't the procedure the same except for the explicit naming of the repo? If it does matter, then a personal site.

Comment: They're similar, but which branch you use is different. Plus, a project specific site usually has the project code in the other branches whereas a personal site just has the site code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like what [Octopress](http://octopress.org/) does where you add your `site` directory to your `.gitignore` and then have a separate repo inside the `site` directory. Now when you push your site's source, push it to a branch called `source`. Then, go into your `site` directory, add your github repo as a remote, and push to the `master` branch (or the `gh-pages` branch if it's a project site). You have to be careful with this approach or else you might end up merging one branch into the other.

With all of that being said, I really would recommend looking into using something like [Octopress](http://octopress.org/) or [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/). I use Octopress for my own blog and it works great. Note that [github pages uses Jekyll behind the scenes](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages) so as long as you push up Jekyll formatted files, github pages handles the generation and displaying of things correctly for you.

Comment: Cheers. This absolutely has to be done by a script or else I know it'll go south.

Answer (score 0):

to host any static website in github, put that code in index.html. whatever code will be there in index.html that will be hosted. then go to setting of your repository. there you will get section for github pages.
select branch name in which index.html file is there and you want to host the page.
and then select the folders name as root. and then save. you will get one link. check this link after 2-3 minutes. you will get your website hosted.